# For loop adding to a variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a loop that adds 1 to a int variable every time the if statement is true

But while testing the code even though the if statement is true the variable is not incremented, as if the my for loop is not incremented at all....

Code sample:

```
int left_jab_count;
if(area >=100000 && area1 <100000)
{
    cout<<"LEFT JAB HAS BEEN THROWN"" "<<area<<endl;

    for(int left_jab_count = 0; left_jab_count < 0 ;++left_jab_count)
    {
        cout<<"Left Jab :"<<left_jab_count<<endl;
    }
}
```

can anybody see where am going wrong here ?

Comment: Why are you declaring `left_jab_count` twice?

Comment: Also, get in the habit of using SPACEBAR

Answer (score 7):

```
 for(int left_jab_count = 0; left_jab_count < 0 ;++left_jab_count)
                                        //^^^^left_jab_count is never < 0
                                        // change <0 to some value larger than 0
```

you `for` loop is never executed. Therefore, `left_jab_count` will never get incremented, you never enter the body of `for` loop.

Meanwhile, you declared `left_jab_count` twice.

Comment: And declaring `left_jab_count` twice means that the one declared in the `for` loop hides the other one, but only while in the `for` loop.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone yes, agreed.

Comment: thx for your replay...... I have tried to change the middle bit of my for loop as suggested to this :  int left_jab_count = 0;
 `if(area >=100000 && area1 <100000)
 {
  cout<<"LEFT JAB HAS BEEN THROWN"" "<<area<<endl;
  
  
  for(int left_jab_count = 0; left_jab_count < 1 ;++left_jab_count)
  {
   cout<<"Left Jab :"<<left_jab_count<<endl;
   
  }
 }`

Comment: but the the Left Jab_count always equals to 0

Comment: @Tomazi since you set upper bound to 1, when loop body is printed, value is 0, then it get incremented to 1, but at this time, loop body is not executed. try to change to 2 instead if only want to change the value from 0 to 1 not other values.

Comment: yes you are right here and with everything you have written but i need this for loop to be dynamic.....meaning that the if stetment might be meet on many occasions there fore I need left_jab_count variable to increment by one every time the condition is meet

Comment: @Tomazi if this is the case, then you should look at JBently's post, it does what you want. I should not repeat what JBently has already answered.

Answer (score 2):

tacp has adequately covered the issues with your current code, so I won't go into those. Based on your specification, *"I am trying to create a loop that adds 1 to a int variable every time the if statement is true"*, what you want is something like this:

```
int left_jab_count = 0; // Don't forget to initialise this

while (true) // Replace with real loop
{
    // Do NOT initialise left_jab_count here, otherwise it will be
    // reset to 0 on every loop

    // Insert code which changes area and area1

    if (area >= 100000 && area1 < 100000)
    {
        cout << "LEFT JAB HAS BEEN THROWN " << area << endl;
        left_jab_count++;
    }
}
```

Unless you've misstated your specification, then you don't need a `for` loop inside the `if` block.

Comment: I have also tried your solution but the variable is only incremented once.....in second instance or third etc. nothing happens

Comment: @Tomazi Then you need to re-state your problem, because according to you, incrementing only once is exactly the behaviour you want - *"adds 1 to a int variable every time the if statement is true"*. You need to re-enter the `if` block multiple times for it to increment multiple times.

Comment: I know and i do enter the if statement more than once and it is always 1

Comment: @Tomazi Ok, well in that case it sounds to me like maybe you're including `int left_jab_count = 0` *inside* the loop where the `if` block resides. Place it *before* any the block where all of that logic lies.

Comment: @Tomazi If you're still stuck after this, please post the entire relevant code as a new question.

Comment: @Tomazi I mean replace it with your code in which you're doing things with `area` and `area1`. I have no idea what your intentions are, so I just did a `while (true)` to demonstrate that it is a loop of some kind. Presumably it **is** a loop if the `if` statement is going to be executed more than once? Really I think the best thing at this point, since the original problem is solved (the variable not being incremented at all), is to post a brand new question, with more complete code as an example, and we can try to help you again.

Comment: Well all i want to achieve here is to increment the variable by one every time the if statement condition is meet.....area & area1 are just as the variable name suggest areas of bounding boxes that i use.....and if one of the boxes is bigger than 100000 then i need to classifieds it as something in my case "Left Jab", in my program i have a very same statement for area1....SO all i need to do is to count how many times each condition has been meet

Comment: If i do that I will receive a lot of downvotes....Happened to me before :D people take it as spamming or dont like same question to appear twice

Answer (score 0):

JBentley answered the question which was set by you. In the While statement that he posted you should add a condition which is true so that the code inside can run. I guess you want to enter:

```
while (left_jab_count < NUMBER)
```

Be sure to have a true condition so that the loop can start and run the if statement.